# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

Tags: sql

Раскопал странную странность, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient работает не так как ожидалось. Смотрю таблицу в sql студии без ключей и читаю в авалонии ту же таблицу без ключей, последовательность  совсем другая. Выяснил что причина в селекте

```
select name,shets,aktiw from soft.dbo.shet
```

дает правильную последовательность, а

```
select name,shets from soft.dbo.shet
```

не правильную. При чем после name,shets можно поставить любое оставшееся поле и все пойдет правильно. И чего делать? Чем можно еще воспользоваться? ODBC подходит для авалонии?

Comment: Без явного указания сортировки `order by` порядок строк не гарантирован. Это азы реляционных СУБД.

Comment: К Авалонии это не имеет никакого отношения. Провайдер тоже роли не играет.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov , по моему без ордера должен быть порядок "физического" положения строк и у sql так и есть . Попробуйте 1000000 раз сделать селект без ордера и увидеть другой порядок . Только дело вовсе не в ордере а в изменении его в зависимости от полей селекта и это ни в какие рамки не лезет , правда виноват я сам , использовал Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.2.0-preview4.23342.2 и забыл об этом, на него уже есть обновление и все с той же ошибкой , поставил System.Data.SqlClient и все наладилось .

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient является устаревшей библиотекой, лучше отказаться от неё в пользу более новой Microsoft.Data.SqlClient. / Я могу лишь повторить: Без явного указания сортировки order by порядок строк не гарантирован. Это азы реляционных СУБД. Подробное описание такого поведения тянет на большую статью. И таких статей в интернете немеряно.

Comment: Ну дело не в порядке от слова совсем а в изменении порядка в зависимости от состава селекта , использовать такую библиотеку лучше сразу застрелиться , у старой библиотеки с надежностью все в порядке и кстати еще с версии sql 7 селект без ордера давал возможность увидеть порядок ввода строк и это разумно .

Comment: Как только на реальной работе вы напишете запрос без явного `order by`, вас сразу с позором уволят. Dixi.

Comment: Меня невозможно уволить, а без ордера у меня есть селекты с sql 7 с 1996 года .